# Deploying GIT repository via FTPS to a shared hosting

Tags: wordpress, deployment, git

I would like to start using GIT for version controling. Here are my prerequisites:

- I'm on **Windows**
- Most of the time I would need to work on **Wordpress templates**
- I have to deploy on multiple shared hosting services - **no SSH access**
- Some of the hosting services **offer GIT hosting**, but the connection is **only via HTTP (WebDav)**

I think the solution might be:

1. Clone https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton to a local **main repo** to have always updated WP installation.
2. Turn on **Wordpress multi-site** to be able to develop more plugins on one WP installation.
3. Develop **Wordpress themes locally as GIT submodules** - *should I then add paths to the WP themes to main repo's .gitignore to not to track changes twice (main repo+submodule)?*
4. **Commit changes to BitBucket** account to have all of the repos at one place
5. When deploying:

   - on hosting with GIT: add **remote GIT repository** (on the hosting), push to the repository via WebDav from the local repo and deploy
   - on hosting without GIT: use something like - **git-ftp**: http://anantgarg.com/2013/09/25/git-ftp-for-windows/ to copy the changed files from local GIT to remote hosting via FTP - *but I wasn't able to find if it is possible to upload via FTPS*

What are the disadvantages to this? Is there a better (free!) solution?

BTW: is it safe (secure connection) to connect to a remote repository like: https://username:password@myhosting.tld ? Won't anyone be able to see the username and password?